# How to fix 'parentMessageSource of the messageSourceBean' so it's not always null

Tags: java, validation, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am creating an API with spring boot with custom validation messages and I am always getting the *org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'name.of.my.message' for locale 'en_US'* exception when I try to get the messages from the **messages.properties** file.

At first I thought it was because of the locale so I tried to have my own **LocaleResolver @Bean** to set the default locale to US and change the messages.properties file name to messages_en_us.properties, but it did not fix the issue.

I finally thought that maybe it was because of the **messageSource object** and I think I was right. When I debugged, I saw that the **messageSource object** has **parentMessageSource** at null and when I stepped into the **getMessage()** method, I saw that if **parentMessageSource** is null it will throw the *NoSuchMessageException*. I am not finding a lot about this specific issue, this is why I am asking this question here.

This my code in application.java (until I make it work):

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {

    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new 
        ResourceBundleMessageSource ();

    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}   

@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator(MessageSource messageSource) {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return bean;
}
```

messages.properties :

```
user.firstName.NotNull=First name must not be null.
```

From all the tutorials I read, this is only what I need to get my validation messages, but, because of the parentMessageSource at null, it is not possible even if the rest of my code seems okay.

Comment: The exception suggests that Spring is trying to lookup the property in `messages_en_US.properties`. The quickest way to get rid of the exception is to copy `messages.properties` to `messages_en_US.properties` in the same directory.

Comment: I already tried that and it is not the problem unfortunately. The MessageSource object has a parentMessageSource property that's always null. To get my messages I need to use the getMessage() method from MessageSource, but this method will throw the exception when parentMessageSource is null. Where I am stuck is that I do not know why it is null and how to fix. I can't seem to find anything that adresses this problem. Thanks for your help though, I really appreciate that you took the time to answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the solution.

It was quite simple actually. My own misunderstanding of Spring boot is at fault here. Basically, in my test class, I need to add the annotations `@ConfigurationContext (classes = Application.java, MyCustomValidationConfig.java)`and it worked ! Thanks to everyone who took a look. Now I just need to figure out out test @valid !